# Chunk array in javascript by adding only 1 element from next chunk

Tags: javascript, arrays, chunks

I am looking to divide my array in JavaScript into chunk of 3. But I only want to increment the chunk by 1 element. Example below:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] => [1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [4,5,6], [5,6,7], [6,7,8]
```

All the resulted arrays should be of size 3. So only the one element is swiped to the left.

I have following code which divides the array into chunk of 3:

```
_.chunk($scope.substituteItems, 3);
```

This code divides the array as:
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] => [1,2,3], [3,4,5], [5,6,7], [8]

Obviously this code is only dividing the array into equal chunks which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to loop through the array. Use `slice()` to shallow copy the array into chunks.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
let numOfChunk = 3;

let result = arr.reduce((c, v, i, a) => {
  if (i + numOfChunk <= a.length) c.push(a.slice(i, i + numOfChunk));
  return c;
}, [])


console.log(result);
```

---

You can also use `concat()` instead of `push()` if you prefer one line of code.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
let numOfChunk = 3;

let result = arr.reduce((c, v, i, a) => i + numOfChunk <= a.length ? c.concat([a.slice(i, i + numOfChunk)]) : c, [])

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

using native js...
If your array of `n` elements is to be chunked into chunks of size `c` sequentially as you describe, there will be `n-c+1` total chunks, in your case `8-3+1=6`, map the first `n-c+1` elements of the array to the chunk containing itself + the next 2:

```
let c=3, arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
let result=arr.slice(0,arr.length-c+1).map((v,k)=>arr.slice(k,k+c));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Also the code has to be compatible with IE. IE doesn't support let command.

Comment: just use `var` instead of let and it should work exactly the same